# How to recursively restore older folder version in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, data-recovery, system-restore, filesystem-corruption

While working on the computer (Windows 7 - HP Laptop), I tried to move a large folder and the system/operation froze. I tried to kill the process from the task manager, then restarted the computer.  After the restart the folder was missing from the original and the target location. I thought, if I restored to a point few days earlier, I would get the folders back. The folders seems to be there, but many files are missing (except execution files). However, if I do a "restore to a previous version" on an individual folder it seems to restore the files, but not recursively.  It would take a long time to restore each folder individually. Are there any solutions to this issue? How can I determine if this a wider corruption of data/files/folders?  Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to do this with the built-in tools that WIndows provides.  There are third-party solutions that offered better features of course

Comment: Any specific suggestions?

Comment: What good would giving you third-party backup solutions do.  Your current backup solution doesn't support the type of restoration you require.  Furthermore we don't really product suggestions here at Superuser.